# Inheriting accessors in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, readonly, setter, accessor

this is my first post; this site has been an invaluable resource.

I'm fairly new to objective-c so please bear with.

So I have a base class with a few properties which I want "private" so I made them readonly. To be clear, I don't want them mutable externally, but I DO wan't to use the 'set' accessor within this class. So...

```
// .h file
@interface Vehicle
@property (nonatomic, readonly) int speed;
@end
```

Also I repeated the property declaration within a category interface block to make the accessors writable in this class

```
// .m file
//Private properties and methods
@interface Vehicle()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int speed;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize speed = _speed;
- (void) someMethod {
    [self setSpeed:10]; // Works fine
}

@end
```

But now if I inherit this class the derived class no longer has the set accessor method (setSpeed in my case). Do I need to synthesize again? Seems like that would defeat the purpose of inheritence. I know i can modify the instance variable directly (_speed = 10;) but would rather not. I'm sure there's something wrong with my understanding. Thanks!

```
// Example
@interface Ship : Vehicle
@end

@implementation
- (void) someOtherMethod {
    [self setSpeed: 2]; // DOES NOT WORK, would like it to
}
@end
```

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how do I inherit that private @interface someName() category..

Comment: I'm guessing you can share the private interface through a header only intended for derived classes to include. (I haven't tried this myself, hence the comment instead of an answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But now if I inherit this class the derived class no longer has the set accessor method (setSpeed in my case).

Actually, it does have the set accessor, it's just that the compiler doesn't know about it.  You have a choice:

- put the class extension (the `@interface Vehicle() .... @end` bit in a separate header file that gets imported into the `.m` for Vehicle and its subclasses (or use a category)
- redeclare the read/write property in a class extension for the subclass.  To avoid a warning, use `@dynamic speed` in the subclass's implementation.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I vaguely remember reading about @dynamic at some point. This sounds right since you and Marcelo are on the same track. Extra++ points for the multiple solutions. I will try it when I get home to my mac and mark this correct. Any way to do this with protocols? Redeclaring seems tedious but I can live with it. Thanks again.

Comment: UPDATE: Tested the above, works great. I realized both solutions are actually the same, the extra header file just saves having to copy/paste that block. Also noted that it does NOT throw a warning if I use synthesize instead of dynamic nor does the functionality change.

Comment: @Patrick: If you use `@synthesize` it will generate new accessors and probably a new ivar for the subclass, so use `@dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't make that distinction. That's what I want though, new ivars in the subclasses. Not accessing base class variables. Considering the quantity of subclasses I will have the #import solution seems to work best. Generally speaking, I wish there was an easy way to inherit methods that are only in the .m implementation file.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no such thing as 'protected' methods, you need to create a private shared header where your anonymous category goes. Then both your original implementation and your derived classes include this header to get access to this 'private' stuff.

Comment: Well said, I suppose there is no naming convention for the header file in this approach. I am using BaseClassNamePrivate, but this is trivial.